# Error adding libraries to gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-recyclerview, android-gradle-plugin

When I try to insert the recyclerview library in my gradle I get back this message and I can't do it

This is the line I want to insert

> compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'

And this is the error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
>   Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' inproject ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.

I am using Android Studio 3.0.1 on ArchLinux

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire `build.gradle` file in which you are trying to add this line.

Comment: Did you click the link for details? Did you try using the 27 version of RecyclerView that matches the error?